# Is this class AB design OK? I get distortion at the output

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, amplifier

[image]

I'm need of an amp that could charge small capacitors 'fast'. The capacitors are actually a disc with one side grounded and the other side coated in oxide so effectivly this is a series of small caps as the disc keeps moving. By charging the caps to different voltages, data is stored on the disc.

The circuit is not very complex, there is a non-inverting JFET input op amp that gets an audio signal and outputs it into a class AB BJT amp. The transistor bias is set using a textbook trick for self biasing of sorts. The negative feedback for the op amp is taken from the output of the transistor amp through a resistor that sets the gain together with R8 (it's actually a 50K trimmer). The problem I am having is that the output is distorted at any gain setting. Is there something fundamentally flawed in the design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no DC feedback in this amplifier at all so the LF347 will hit the end stops and distortion will prevail: -

[image]

Where did you get this crappy design from? Also, why are you wanting to use a class AB amplifier to charge capacitors? Why not just use a MOSFET switch?

Comment: True, I did not notice there is no DC feedback, so I need to add some feedback from the output of the op amp before the 100uF cap? How can I determine the value of this resistor, but is should be a fixed value right? The same value should work for whatever gain setting I have there? This is sourced from a user manual of an echo unit. How can I use a mosfet switch to charge in co-relation to a modulating waveform?

Comment: Before I give more advice on your amplifier you should explain and justify why you need to use the amp to achieve what you want.

Comment: fair enough, I simply start with a given design because I don't want to re-invent the wheel sort of speak. An op amp by itself won't be able to to drive the low capacitive load (I tried).

Comment: Then don't use that op-amp - you can get op-amps that can drive several amps OR add a simple one-transistor buffer onto an op-amp. You don't need a push-pull class AB stage for charging a capacitor dude.

Comment: OK, so you don't want to reinvent the wheel. http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa600b/snoa600b.pdf

Comment: And you really haven't given enough information. 1 - What is the capacitance of your disks? If you don't know this, you're in trouble. 2 - What voltage levels are you trying to achieve, and with what resolution?  3 - How fast do you need to do this?

Comment: Finally, in addition to just brute-force providing the current you need to charge and discharge the cap in the time required, you need to be aware that driving capacitive loads is a good way to send an opamp unstable. Google "op amp capacitive load" and start reading.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast well said dude

Comment: Thanks for the links. Regarding a mosfet, is that actually needs to be a JFET because I need not just ON/OFF but a linear region for the charging according to the input signal. Also, if I add DC feedback in the above design it should make it work OK, no? How can I calc the resistor needed there?

Comment: If all you want is to charge the cap fast then any saturating transistor will do this. If in fact you need something more esoteric then you should consider amending your question. This site is about good answers to decent or great questions.

Comment: @Andyaka - please note that the OP states "By charging the caps to different voltages". So a MOSFET to a single supply voltage won't work.

Comment: @user34920 - First, you've missed the point. To get DC feedback, just get rid of C2. Second, get rid of Q1. You still haven't answered the question of why you think you need an AB stage. Third, connect the output of your opanp to the junction of R4 and R5. Fourth, R6 and R7 may be too large. Please respond to my earlier question about your requirements. Fifth, if you just hook up the output to your caps, the circuit may well oscillate. See my previous comment and start reading. Finally, if your source really does have an average of zero, get rid of R1 and C1.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to save this design by making a few changes to the circuit.

[image]

[image]

Whether this meets your needs will be impossible to tell because it is not known just exactly what your parametric requirements are. At least this minimizes the distortion at the output.

Comment: that's great and very elegant :)

Comment: @Michael - How about, just for fun, you add a 1uF cap to ground to Vout?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - Yeah, I know. Try even a 50 or 100 ohm load to GND from Vout. I didn't put a load and this because the original poster never even showed where he intended the output to be then yet what the load would be - other than his vague description about some disks. It's still a crappy circuit.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - Yup. But notice that if you didn't increase the gain, it would do okay for 50 ohm loads.